# Gray vertical bars appearing in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have installed a Google maps API into a mobile version of one of my websites, I am having an issue with gray vertical bars appearing every 300px or so throughout the map, does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? Ive tried setting map resize functions and center coordinates but no luck. I havent been able to come across another problem like mine with a solution... you can see an example of what I am talking about at http://encorewebplus.com/mobilerestaurant/HIGHEND/#ourlocation (if you drag and resize window you will see the issue)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would say tidy up your code first. In "ourmap.html" you have this:

    <script>#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 725px;
 }
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

Remove this style from ourmap.html:

```
img { border: 0; width: 95%; display: block; max-width: 95%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:2%;}
```

the issue is forced by `max-width: 95%;`

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle, cant believe it was that simple and I overlooked it. Works perfectly.

Comment: In my case it was a `min-height`. I added this to fix it: `#map img {max-width: none!important; max-height: none!important}`. Thanks for the direction. @Dr. Molle: You saved the day!