# Google Maps API: max-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble when trying to fix the vertical bands issue on Google Maps API for javascript.

The fact is that I only have access to the jQuery that is loaded automatically by the CRM.

In fact, I need to set the `max-width` property to `none` for all the img tags inside my Map div (#map-canvas).

This works if I edit the HTML code directly from Firefox Tools, but I can't find a way to have this done automatically.

The code I have access to looks like this:

```
var mymap;

jQuery.Class("MapView",{
    initialize:function(){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 45.447541, lng: 11.7451883},
        zoom: 14
    };
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
},{});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    mymap = MapView.initialize();
});

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#map-canvas').find('img').css('max-width: none');
    $("#map-canvas").hide().fadeIn('fast');
});
```

I tried a bunch of other online tutorials, but I've not been able to solve this.

Does anyone know a way to pull me out of this?

Thanks,
Riccardo

EDIT:
So, here's my complete code up to now:

```
var mymap;
var mymap_markers = [];

jQuery.Class("MapView",{
    registerOnChangeEventOfSourceModule: function () {
        jQuery('#sourceModule').on('change', function (e) {
            jQuery('#picklistFields').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="--">--</option>').val('--');

            var element = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
            var params = {};
            var sourceModule = element.val();

            params = {
                'module': 'Map',
                'action': "GetCVAjax",
                'mode': "changeModule",
                'sourceModule': sourceModule
            };

            AppConnector.request(params).then(
                function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        jQuery.each(data.result.options, function (i, item) {
                            var o = new Option(item, i);
                            jQuery(o).html(item);
                            jQuery("#picklistFields").append(o);
                            jQuery("#picklistFields").trigger('liszt:updated');
                        });
                    }
                },
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            );
        });
    },

    registerOnChangeEventOfCustomView: function () {
        jQuery('#picklistFields').on('change', function (e) {
            var element = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
            var params = {};
            var cvid = element.val();
            var module = jQuery('#sourceModule').val();

            params = {
                'module': 'Map',
                'action': "GetCVAjax",
                'mode': "getMarkers",
                'sourceModule': module,
                'cvid': cvid
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < mymap_markers.length; i++) {
                mymap_markers[i].setMap(mymap);
            }
            mymap_markers = [];

            AppConnector.request(params).then(
                function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        jQuery.each(data.result, function (i, item) {
                            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item['coords']['lat'],item['coords']['lng']);
                            var popupcontentCV = "<table class=\"table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered\"><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><strong>"+item['title']+"</strong></td></tr>";

                            jQuery.each(item['data'], function (label, value){
                                popupcontentCV += "<tr><td>"+app.vtranslate(label,module)+"</td><td>"+value+"</td></tr>";
                            });
                            popupcontentCV += "</table>";

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: popupcontentCV,
                                maxWidth: 315,
                                maxHeight: 550
                            });

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                map: mymap,
                                title: item['data']['title']
                            });

                            mymap_markers.push(marker);

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.open(mymap,marker);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                },
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            );
        });
    },

    initialize:function(){
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: 45.447541, lng: 11.7451883},
          zoom: 14
        };

        return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
},{});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    mymap = MapView.initialize();
    MapView.registerOnChangeEventOfSourceModule();
    MapView.registerOnChangeEventOfCustomView();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(mymap, 'idle', function () {
    $('#map-canvas img').css('max-width', 'none');
});
/*
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#map-canvas').find('img').css('max-width: none');
    $("#map-canvas").hide().fadeIn('fast');
});*/
```

Comment: What's the *vertical bands issue* please? There is no reason why you should override the maps CSS.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, the issue is reported in lots of places, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050808/gray-vertical-bars-appearing-in-google-maps. I have to override the maps CSS because, as I said, I don't have access to any other part of the CRM, and I know somewhere the property "max-width: 95%" is applied to all img elements (thus, also to the map ones), causing the issue.

Comment: So what CSS rule have you tried? `#map-canvas img { max-width: none; }`?

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I tried to do like the last function in the snippet. I need to set max-width to none for all img entities under map-canvas div. Sadly, it appears that the styles don't apply if I do like so. Setting it globally doesn't work either. It's kinda like if the img style gets overwritten after my operation. By the way, $('#map-canvas').find('img') returns a lot of img entities, so they are already there when i execute .css(...)

Comment: Didn't see your edit. Yes, I tried exactly that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either a CSS rule or with jQuery:

**CSS**

```
#map-canvas img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
    $('#map-canvas img').css('max-width', '100%');
});
```

I am not sure whether you should set the `max-width` to `none` or `100%`. Try both. And maybe try to write your CSS rule with `!important` if it doesn't work right away.

For the jQuery version, I added the `css()` function within the map `idle` event listener (therefore you are sure the map is loaded and ready).

**Edit**

I can't test your code but you can try this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    mymap = MapView.initialize();

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mymap, 'idle', function () {
        $('#map-canvas img').css('max-width', '100%');
    });

    MapView.registerOnChangeEventOfSourceModule();
    MapView.registerOnChangeEventOfCustomView();
});
```

Comment: I tried this. Same outcome. I put it in replacement of this: `$(window).bind("load", function() {`

Comment: Please paste your **complete code** in your question.

Comment: Done, I posted it in the question

Comment: See my edit. Maybe do a `console.log` in the event listener to make sure it gets there.

Comment: I did so. It does register the listener, and it does execute it once the map is idle. But still, the img tags inside the map are still missing the max-width property. :(

Comment: Did you try with both `none` and `100%` properties?

Comment: And via CSS? `#map-canvas img { max-width: 100% !important; }` ? Also can you share a live URL to your site?

Comment: I don't have access to the css file. I can only operate via jQuery. :(

Comment: I can add files wherever i want... Shall I load it from jquery?

Comment: Why not. Try it. And/or provide a live URL.

Comment: I don't have a live Url. It's on my dev machine... I will try adding a css with important rule, however, and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Oh, right, I totally forgot. I'll do that in a fizzy.